# How to store 64 bit integers using oracle::occi::Statement::setDataBuffer()?

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

Using OCCI (Oracle C++ Call Interface), I would like to use `setDataBuffer()` to insert 64 bit integer values into an Oracle table with a NUMBER(19) column.  If I pass an array of 64 bit int's to setDataBuffer() and set the data size to 64 bits (8 bytes), OCCI still only uses 32 bits.  The documentation on [Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNCPP/types.htm#LNCPP20214) does not have an entry for 64 bit int's.  Is there a way to insert these large numbers using `setDataBuffer()`?

Comment: I'd also like to know, I've made a workaround using the "setDouble" method despite the large number of warnings.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535202/best-way-to-store-an-unsigned-64-bit-integer-in-oracle-database-11g-using-occi